# Problem with pdfpages due to everyshi related error

Tags: errors, pdfpages

I just want to add individual .pdf pages to my final latex document. A snippet of the code is presented below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.50in, bottom=1.50in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

...

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{color}

...
```

And this is why it tells me:

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `eso-pic',
>                  but the package provides`everyshi'.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined.
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.

I am using TeX Live 2012, on Ubuntu 11.10, with the pdflatex command for compilation.

Comment: Something must be seriously broken with your setup. Study the logfile for clues.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error with the code snipset:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.50in, bottom=1.50in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

The file runs without errors or warnings.
The version list:

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
pdfpages.sty    2012/04/03 v0.4s Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 eso-pic.sty    2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
pppdftex.def    2012/04/03 v0.4s Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
 balance.sty    1999/02/23 4.3 (PWD)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********
```

---

In the comments the OP assumes the following as culprit:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*((x-#1)/#2)^2)}%
}
```

The function can be found in the [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_gaussienne):

[image: Gauss function]

Then μ and σ are the first and second parameter of your new function `gauss`. But there is a third paramter, the function argument `x` itself.

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*((#3-#1)/#2)^2)}%
}
```

Then the function is called with three arguments: μ, σ, and x.
    \pgfmathparse{gauss(0,1,2)}

The function can also be optimized. For example, the calculations with constants can be moved outside:

```
\pgfmathparse{1/(sqrt(2*pi)}
\let\gaussAux\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{\gaussAux/#2*exp(-0.5*((#3-#1)/#2)^2)}%
}
```

Comment: Yes, well, perhaps I should provide a more conclusive code sample, here it is: http://ctrlv.it/latex/MzA4MzA5, and oddly enough your example compiled on my system; concluding it has to be related to one of my settings, but which one and why ?! Thank you Heiko.

Comment: The example runs without error here. Strip the example down until you know, where the culprit is, update the package(s) and try again.

Comment: I found the problem area. Commented the part with {pgfplots}, i.e. http://ctrlv.it/id/MzA4NDIx, and it compiled with no error. Unfortunately, I need that {gauss} function. Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Does anybody know a solution for this problem ?